# Unsuccessful flask app deployment on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, mod-wsgi, flask

I am trying to deploy a flask app on an Amazon EC2 instance. I have configured everything just fine but the website does not load. It remains stuck on the loading icon as follows:

[Website not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzjRA.png)

Even the logs dont show any error:

[Apache Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ4aA.png)

The directory structure of my app is as follows:

```
/var/www/html/
        |--ImgClassApp.wsgi
        |--/ImgClassApp
         |--1000_imagenet_classes_file.txt
         |--app.py
         |--app_helper.py
         |--requirements.txt
         |--/static
            |--/css
            |--/uploads
         |--/templates
            |--index.html
            |--layout.html
            |--upload.html
```

Following are the contents of my WSGI script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/html/ImgClassApp')
from app import app as application
```

And following is the WSGI part of the apache conf file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ImgClassApp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/ImgClassApp.wsgi

<Directory ImgClassApp>
        WSGIProcessGroup ImgClassApp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

SSH and HTTP are allowed for all from the EC2 security group settings and all other settings are default.